# How to set flags in ember-cli, other than environment?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

This is currently possible:

```
ember build --environment=production
```

... and I would like to do something like this instead:

```
ember build --environment=production --baseurl=foo
```

but `config/environment.js` only gets passed in the value of `environment`.

Is it possible to get the value of the other options passed in at the command line too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set environment variables the old fashioned way (`export WHATEVER=wee`) from terminal or as part of a build script, then reference them in your `Brocfile.js` via node with `process.env.WHATEVER`. After that, it would be a matter of having broccoli do whatever it is you needed to do with them. You could pre-process files and replace strings, for example.

... just a suggestion. Not sure if that's what you're looking for or not.

Comment: @ Ben Lesh thanks for the answer. That was indeed how I solved the problem (before asking the question even).  +1 and check to you! ... I just wanted to know if ember-cli allowed additional parameters/ arguments.

Comment: is it possible to run something like **ember server --environment=test**

Comment: You can also access any environment variable directly in your environment.js with process.env.VARNAME

Answer (score 7):

It appears that this is not allowed:

Looking in `node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/build.js`, we see:

```
availableOptions: [
  { name: 'environment', type: String, default: 'development' },
  { name: 'output-path', type: path, default: 'dist/' }
],
```

... and in `node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js`

```
this.availableOptions.forEach(function(option) {
  knownOpts[option.name] = option.type;
});
```

... which together mean that any options that are *not* defined, for each subcommand of `ember`, get discarded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `foo=bar ember build` (however doing `ember build foo=bar` doesn't work)

And the argument is available via `process.env.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

To extend upon @ben's answer.

The raw command line arguments are available inside `ember-cli-build.js` and other files from the

`process.argv.[]`

So a command like this

`ember build staging`

you can access via:

`process.argv.includes('staging')`

see node's documentation for whats available.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html